# Blackberry: Invoke Calculator and Retrieve Value?

Tags: java, blackberry, invoke, calculator

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_CALCULATOR, null);
```

How can I retrieve a value from an invoked calculator back into my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way this would be possible is to create your own Calculator.

You can communicate between two separate applications using [Global Events](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/What_Is_-_Global_Events_and_Global_Event_Listeners.html?nodeid=800527&vernum=0), however these need to be your own applications.